# Create string to be used to read in json response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to get a particular element in a json using a dedicated function, but I can't figure out why it's not working. Can anyone help me?

I set up a fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/N5TTM/2/

CODE:

```
var data = {
   "results":[
      {
         "reinsurance":{
            "africa":{
               "one":{
                  "name":"test",
                  "address":"test street",
                  "tel1":"tel1",
                  "tel2":"tel2",
                  "url":"http://www.google.com"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}

// FAKE RESPONSE

var AjaxInfo = {

init : function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},

bindEvents : function() {
    var self = this;

    $(document).ready(function() {

        self.renderData( 'reinsurance', 'africa', 'one' );

    })
},

renderData : function( category, country, name ) {

    console.log(data.results[0]); //ok
    console.log(data.results[0].category); //I pass 'insurance' as a category but it returns "undefined" because it looks for "category" instead

}
}

AjaxInfo.init();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use category like this

```
console.log(data.results[0][category]);
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/N5TTM/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Since `category` is not a property itself, but a reference to a property you cannot use `.` operator to access the value, you need to use `[]` operator instead.

```
data.results[0][category]
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/d6MgU/)

Answer (score 0):

use `[]` to get the related object reference.. `.` is for object property

```
 console.log(data.results[0][category])
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/N5TTM/4/)